# Searching and counting a specific word in a text file Java

Tags: java, file, count, cpu-word

I've been trying to write a program that reads from a text file, searches for a word, and counts how many instances of that word is in the file.

**This would be a sample output:**

```
*Enter the name of the text file:
input.dat
Enter the word you're searching for in text file:
that
The word "that" appeared 3 times in the file input.dat*
```

***EDIT***

My Data file is located in 
*C:\Users\User1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WordCounter*
it's named *superfish* and contains the words:

super 
super
fresh 
super
fish
supper
fash
sooper
foosh
Super
sUPer
SUPer

**This is the output I get after entering my inputs**

`*run:
   Enter the name of the text file:
   superfish.txt
   Enter the word you are searching for in the text file:
   super
   The word "super" appeared 0 times in the file superfish.txt*`

This is the code that I have written so far, the main issue is that count returns 0 whenever it is run.

I've searched for solutions everywhere and I just can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class WordCounter 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter the name of the text file:");
       String name = keyboard.nextLine();
       File file = new File(name);

       System.out.println("Enter the word you are searching for in the text file:");
       String word = keyboard.nextLine();

       try
       {
           System.out.println("The word \""+word+"\" appeared "+ searchCount(file,word) +  " times in the file "+ file); 
       }    
       catch (IOException e) 
       {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }


    }

    public static int searchCount(File fileA, String fileWord) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        int count = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileA);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String nextWord = scanner.next();
            System.out.println(nextWord);
            if (nextWord.equalsIgnoreCase(fileWord))
            count++;

        }
        //End While 
        return count;
    }   
}
```

Comment: `I just can't understand what I'm doing wrong` you are not comparing string `fileWord` to file content anywhere

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything at all

Comment: Just edited it, accidentally left out the if statement when cutting and pasting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`searchCount` has two big problems:

1. It doesn't actually count :-)
2. It checks if the scanner has another line, but reads only a single word.

Here's a revised version of `searchCount` which fixes both issues:

```
public static int searchCount(File fileA, String fileWord) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    int count = 0;
    fileWord = fileWord.trim();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileA);

    while (scanner.hasNext()) // Fix issue #2
    {
        String nextWord = scanner.next().trim();
        if (nextWord.equals(fileWord)) { // Fix issue #1
            ++count; 
        }
    }
    //End While 
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but now I have another issue, the count returns as 0 even though I am entering the exact same word that I've written 10 ten times in my data file

Comment: @Ariver Probably a white-space issue. `trim()`ing should solve this - see my edited answer.

Comment: No, I'm sorry it still doesn't solve the issue. The answer returned for me is still 0 for count.  I made sure I had you answer exactly as you wrote it this time too.

Comment: @Ariver works fine for me... Can you share your file and your input? Are you sure the file is located correctly?

Comment: I made an edit under the sample output, please check and respond. Thank you so much for trying to help by the way!!!

Comment: @Ariver still runs perfectly for me. The only thing I can think of is that either you mis-copied one of the `trim()` calls (note there are two), or you aren't reading the file you think you're reading.

Comment: PRobably the latter suggestion. 
I'll look further into it but I'm glad to know that it works for you. 

Thank you very much!